# Jquery Autocomplete don't work with on the fly element?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, autocomplete

I  am  using  Jquery autocomplete  dynamically  textbox. this  is  working  fine  but  not  working  with  on the  fly element. Any  suggestions?

My code

```
   $('input#ISBN').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetISBN',
            minLength: 1,
            maxRows: 5,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: Apply `autocomplete` after the element is created.

Comment: Are you re-calling this code after the textbox has been dynamically added to the DOM?

Comment: @Curt no  i  am  not  re-calling

Comment: We  need  to  call  by  Live  or  On  but  i don't  know  How  with this code

Comment: @KapsHasija Post the code where you are adding the new element(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to recall your code **after** your element has been added to the DOM.

As you are using an ID selector, my guess is you are only using this for one element, and therefore don't need a loop. If this is for multiple elements, change your ID into a class, and change the selector to:

```
$('input.ISBN')
```

Your code should be something like this:

```
function autoComp(element){
  element.autocomplete({
            source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetISBN',
            minLength: 1,
            maxRows: 5,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            }

  });
}

$(function(){
    $('input#ISBN').each(function () {
       autoComp($(this));
    });
});
```

Then whereever you are dynamically adding the element:

```
//Element added here
//e.g:
$(".foobar").append(newElement);

autoComp(newElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all give ur element same class instead of id than after adding dynamic control you can do this

```
$('input.ISBN').not('.ui-autocomplete-input').each(function () {
        $(this).autocomplete({
            source: '/Cataloging/Bib/GetISBN',
            minLength: 1,
            maxRows: 5,
            select: function (event, ui) {

            }

        });
    });
```